# Implicit differentiation for the given equation

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Determine the first and second derivative of $y$ being given the equation
$x^5+y^5-15=0$

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the implicit function $$F=x^5+y^5-15=0$$ Differentiate $$F'_x=5x^4\qquad F'_y=5y^4\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=-x^4y^{-4}$$ $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-4x^3y^{-4}+4x^{4}y^{-5}\frac{dy}{dx}$$ and continue.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is: (1) Take derivatives of the equation (2) solve for $y'$ resp. $y''$. If you have to take the derivative of some function $g(y)$ with respect to $x$, recall that by the chain rule, we have 
$$  \bigl(g(y)\bigr)' = g'(y)y' $$
Hence, 
$$ (y^5)' = 5y^4y' $$
Taking the derivative of your equation gives 
$$ 5y^4y' + 5x^4 = 0 \tag+$$
Now solve for $y'$. Taking another derivative of $(+)$ gives us 
$$ 20y^3(y')^2 + 5y^4y'' + 20x^3 = 0 $$
Pluging in $y'$ from above and solving for $y''$ gives us the second derivative. I'm sure, you can do the rest.